# Variables shadowing in C - why compiler got confused?

Tags: c, gcc, local-variables

I have this code to parse JSON. The structure has a key, val and pointer to next structure. Due to nesting, the val pointer points sometimes to jss structure.

The code below

```
struct jss {
    uint8_t type;
    char *key;
    char *val;
    struct jss *next;
};

void my_f() {
    ...
    struct jss *js = (struct jss *)malloc(sizeof(struct jss));
    ...
    while(js) {
        struct jss *js1 = (struct jss *)js->val;
        ...
    }
}
```

compiles and runs fine and has this assembly:

```
struct jss *js = (struct jss *)malloc(sizeof(struct jss));
 4ea:   bf 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edi
 4ef:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  4f4 <Init+0x407>
 4f4:   48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
 
    ...
    
        char *t, *f, *h;
        struct jss *js1 = ((struct jss *)(js->val));
 522:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
 526:   48 8b 40 10             mov    0x10(%rax),%rax
 52a:   48 89 45 b0             mov    %rax,-0x50(%rbp)
```

We see that rbp-0x18, which has the addr of js structure is moved to rax, rax then adds 0x10 to point
to js->val address and the result is stored in rbp-0x50 which holds the js1. So far, so good!

But if I change the code to this (js1 is replaced by js):

```
struct jss {
    uint8_t type;
    char *key;
    char *val;
    struct jss *next;
};

void my_f() {
    ...
    struct jss *js = (struct jss *)malloc(sizeof(struct jss));
    ...
    while(js) {
        char *t, *f, *h;
        struct jss *js = (struct jss *)js->val;
        ...
    }
}
```

I have this assembly:

```
struct jss *js = (struct jss *)malloc(sizeof(struct jss));
     4ea:   bf 20 00 00 00          mov    $0x20,%edi
     4ef:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  4f4 <Init+0x407>
     4f4:   48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)

    ...

            char *t, *f, *h;
            struct jss *js = ((struct jss *)(js->val));
     522:   48 8b 45 c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
     526:   48 8b 40 10             mov    0x10(%rax),%rax
     52a:   48 89 45 c8             mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)
```

Which compiles fine but segfaults:
Instead of loading the address of js structure (rbp-0x18) into rax, the loaded address is that of the
new structure I create...then there is no surprise why it segfaults.

The question is what is illegal about the second code. I know about variable shadowing and this is indeed my intention. Why the compiler gets confused (I use gcc) ?

Comment: `struct jss *js1 = (struct jss *)js->val;` I do not understand. Why should `val` be a pointer to a `struct jss`? Why not `next`?

Comment: The compiler does not get confused. You code is simply wrong. If you know about variable shadowing, everything should be clear.

Comment: A struct pointer and a character pointer are not compatible types. You cannot convert from a character pointer to a struct pointer - doing so is invalid C. Are you sure you shouldn't be using `void*` instead? How do you initialize/assign the `val` member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this line of your code:

```
struct jss *js = (struct jss *)js->val;
//          ^                  ^ 
//          |                  |
//          this js  and this js are the same
```

You declare `js` and then you dereference `js`. The second `js` is the same variable than the one being declared and it is of course not initialized hence the segfault.

If you have

```
struct jss *js1 = (struct jss *)js->val;
```

then `js` refers to the `js` declared in the outer scope, which is what you want.

It is the exact same situation as in this simpler situation:

```
int foo = 3;
...
{
   int foo = foo;
   ... // you expect foo to be three here, but actually
       // you're just assigning the unininitialized foo to itself
}
```

BTW [clang issues a very explicit warning in this situation](https://www.godbolt.org/z/71KMWP) but gcc does not.

Comment: thanks! Why does it makes sense to dereference a pointer being defined and not the one with the same name from the outer scope?

Comment: @alexeik it doesn't make sense, but in C you can do a lot of things that dont make sense. Some compilers issue a warning for this, read the updated answer.

Comment: "You can do" in the sense that a compiler accepts the code, @alexeik.  That doesn't imply that that the resulting program necessarily has sensible or even well-defined behavior.  Or that other conforming compilers will necessarily accept it.  Or that any or all of the compilers that accept it will do so without emitting diagnostic messages about it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
> after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
> tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
> appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
> other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of
> its declarator.**

So within this while statement

```
while(js) {
    char *t, *f, *h;
    struct jss *js = (struct jss *)js->val;
    ...
}
```

there is declared identifier `js` that refers to itself in the initializer. That is in the initializer expression there is used indeterminate value of the declared identifier `js` that hides the object with the same identifier .declared in the outer scope before the while statement.